# Object scaling with a radial transition

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made this effect in Cinema 4D, objects scaling radially, but I can't figure out how to do this in Blender using Geometry nodes. Any idea?

[C4D radial transition](https://vimeo.com/857422521)

Comment: You forgot to link the recording. And one more thing, it would be better if you attach it as a gif using the existing tools

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

For an existing collection of objects, however arranged, you could implement this effect with some mapping of a *Gradient > Radial* texture in the space of a modified 'harness' object:

[image]

You can modify the effect with the mapping parameters. To achieve a result similar to the one in your reference. in which the spheres are scaled sequentially, you would pass a clamped segment of scaling values over the collection, by animating an offset of the gradient texture's value:

[image]

producing:

[image]

If you wanted to vary the start-point of the transition, you could add more nodes, or just rotate the harness.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First step, the easiest one. Take a mesh circle with 5 vertices and instance some spheres onto it. Done.

Now scaling these instances, the difficult part, had to bang my head on the wall a bit, but found the solution.

Take a curve circle, and capture the factor attribute. Now using the sample nearest and sample index nodes we will be able to transfer the nearest factor value of the spline to scale the instanced spheres.

Now the finale, the actual magic done to the spline factor to make sure the scaling occurs properly. Multiply the factor by a large number.We are going to clamp the values later so in the end they won't actually scale to that large number. Now use subtract to keep on decreasing the factor around the circle in a sweeping fashion. Remember to tick clamp on this subtract node and not the multiply node.

The node tree:
[image]

Result:
[image]

You can add a map range node in before plugging in the scale in order to limit the scale from  0.1(or basically anything you want) to 1 instead of the current 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following solution:

[image]

This solution should also match the Cinema 4D integrated version well in terms of parameters.

[image]

Here I simply instantiate spheres at a certain number of points of a circle.

The parameters *End Angle* and *End Transition* control the area of action.

By using $index*\frac{2\pi}{count}$ to capture the angle of each point beforehand in the point domain, I can then use `Map Range` to move it to a different range. If *End Transistion* is greater than $0$, I thus map the value for the angle into a range of $0-1$, which I use as scaling for the individual instances.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think the setups in answers are too complicated. Here is the simple setup:

[image]

You just need "map range" node to map sphere index to its scale depends on progress of animation. And put this scale into scale socket of "Instance on points" node. That's enough

Answer (score 2):

I tried too:

[image]

You need to look at them from the bottom so they disappear clockwise:

[image]

Please upvote and accept.

Comment: oops... not quite snap.  Different enough. :)